# Selenium Grid: WebDriverException with Windows 8.1/Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a simple Selenium Grid remote driver initialization
which is failing with an WebDriverException as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

selenium_grid_url='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
caps['platform']="WINDOWS"
caps['version']="8.1"

remotedriver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=caps,
                      command_executor=selenium_grid_url)
```

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Selenium/ChromeBrowser/loginscript.py", line 16, in 
    command_executor=selenium_grid_url)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in **init**
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: **Message: None**
Stacktrace:
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries (:-1)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll (:-1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities. (DesiredCapabilities.java:55)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:104)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:83)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost (DriverServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:543)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1584)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1228)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1553)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1130)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:112)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (:-1)

Process finished with exit code 1

Is something wrong with my invocation?

EDIT:

1. Selenium standalone server version: 3.4.0
2. Java version 1.8.0 (121)
3. Both hub and node of the grid on the same machine.
4. Python version 3.5.2

Comment: What is your Python version/configuration?

Comment: My python version is 3.5.2. What configuration details are you interested in? Thanks.